# Apache log4net changing logging level text

Tags: c#, xml, log4net, log4net-configuration

In Apache Log4net logging utility, the `%level` pattern output the logging level of the logger like: if I call `log.Warn("")`, the output is `Warn`. Is there any way to change the output text. For instance, `log.Info("")` outputs `Information` instead of `INFO`.

Comment: check the patterns (method)  can be overridden or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is [create a custom log event,](http://rageshkrishna.com/2011/01/21/AddingCustomLogLevelsToLog4net.aspx) and modify your PatternLayout format if necessary.

Example usage (from the link):

> The first thing you need to do is to create and register your new levels with the LogManager like this:

```
log4net.Core.Level authLevel = new log4net.Core.Level(50000, "Auth");
log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().LevelMap.Add(authLevel);
It’s important that you do this before configuring log4net.
```

> Adding some extension methods makes it dead simple to start using the new log levels:

```
public static class SecurityExtensions
{
    static readonly log4net.Core.Level authLevel = new log4net.Core.Level(50000, "Auth");

    public static void Auth(this ILog log, string message)
    {
        log.Logger.Log(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, 
            authLevel, message, null);
    }

    public static void AuthFormat(this ILog log, string message, params object[] args)
    {
        string formattedMessage = string.Format(message, args);
        log.Logger.Log(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType,
            authLevel, formattedMessage, null);
    }

}
```

> And that’s it – now I can start using my new “Auth” logging level on any instance of ILog like this:

```
SecurityLogger.AuthFormat("User logged in with id {0} from IP address {1}", id, Request.UserHostAddress);
```